# how to stop bulma css pageloader from laoding forever

Tags: bulma

**guys I  add help with this bulma-pageloader
it loading already but it just keeps loading forever . please how can I stop it**

*this is the link*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\URL/node_modules/bulma-pageloader/dist/css/bulma-pageloader.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="pageloader is-active is-info"><span class="title"> Pageloader</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

*it just keeps loading*

Comment: Things on the internet don't load forever. They timeout. Please provide debug information, share information from the console and the network tab. We cannot help you with just this.

Comment: <div class="pageloader is-active      is-info"><span class="title">

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the snippet for the pageloader element you supplied here is complete and correct but below is what it should look like:

```
<div class="pageloader "><span class="title">Pageloader</span></div>
```

Insert the closing div `(</div>)` and also remove the `is-active` modifier. That should stop it from loading forever.